# Generic type 'ComponentRef<C>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-components

Unable to remove dynamic components in ionic-2. It’s saying  exception while typescript compile

> “Generic type 'ComponentRef' requires 1 type argument(s)”.

Also, the same code is working while using without using ionic2.
Much appreciate your help.
Thanks in Advance.

```
class DynamicCmp {
  _ref: ComponentRef;
  _idx: number;
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver, private location: ViewContainerRef) { }
  remove() {
    this._ref.destroy();
  }
  add1() {
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(DynamicCmp).then((factory: ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      let ref = this.location.createComponent(factory, 0);
      ref.instance._ref = ref;
      ref.instance._idx = this._idx++;
    });
  }
}
```

> Exception:  TypeScript error: ....../home/home.ts(9,11): Erro r
>   TS2314: Generic type 'ComponentRef' requires 1 type argument(s).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ComponentRef` is a generic type. Just change your code the following:

```
class DynamicCmp {
  _ref: ComponentRef<any>; <== add <any>
```

Hope it helps you!